# Converting time from String to Date crashes on Simulator only

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

Currently I am using this code to convert a time from `String` to `Date`:

```
public static func dateFromTime(_ time: String) -> Date {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "k:mm"
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.current

    return formatter.date(from: time)!
}
```

This works on my device, but it crashes on the simulator. Both of them uses the 12 hour format from what I can see.

The string that this method receives when it crashes is `"5:30 AM"`.

Any other reason why this code may crash on simulator and not device ?

Comment: what's you console message when your app crashes? that will address your issue, anyway i strongly, recommend you to use a real device for tests, because the Simulator is always buggy and doesn't say the truth like a real device does ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code crashed because of proper date format !

For , `"5:30 AM"` use `"h:mm a"` , instead of `"k:mm"` .

To avoid any kind of crashes , update your code like below . .

```
public static func dateFromTime(_ time: String) -> Date {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        if let date = formatter.date(from: time)
        {
            return date
        }
        print("Invalid arguments ! Returning Current Date . ")
        return Date()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

small k for 24hours format & capital K for 12 hours(am/pm). If you expect 12hours formatted time then you should use capital K to format this.
[link here](https://support.qualityunit.com/269783-Time--Date-format-patterns)

Hope it helps.